# I'd like to do regression using canonical correlation analysis

Tags: r, machine-learning, partial-least-squares, canonical-correlation, reduced-rank-regression

I got two multidimensional datasets, ***X*** and ***Y***. I thought I build the model, which explains the relationship between two datasets, using **canonical correlation analysis** (CCA). The first correlation between two components(canonical variates) is 0.87. I think which is not so bad.

The problem is I have to do regression. For example, how does Y change what if a new ***X'*** comes in. So I need to get new components of ***Y***, and then  reconstruct it like the original ***Y***.

I am not good at this area, so I can't do anything right now.

For more information, originally the dataset ***X*** has only categorical variables, so I vectorized it into binary (= One-hot encoding). And ***Y*** has 6 variables.

It seems to be related to **Reduced-Rank Regression** or **Partial Least Squares** as far as I know. And if you give me some examples of this using **R**, it would be much helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is your question? If you ask about code I think it is off-topic for the site, if your question is about how valid is your approach, it could be on topic

Comment: The approach is the main question.I just want to know how valid my approach and share idea of other people.  As you can read, R code is just extra if it is possible.